# Cofusing about lookup node with binary tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I build a binary tree with python code, now I could print it in order with `testTree.printInorder(testTree.root)`. I have tried to lookup some node ,and the function `findNode` doesn't work anymore . `print testTree.findNode(testTree.root,20)` whatever I put in just return None.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None;
        self.right = None;
        self.data = value;


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def addNode(self,node,value):
        if node == None:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)
        else:
            if value < node.data:
                if node.left == None:
                    node.left = TreeNode(value)
                else:
                    self.addNode(node.left,value)
            else:
                if node.right == None:
                    node.right = TreeNode(value)
                else:
                    self.addNode(node.right,value)

    def printInorder(self,node):
        if node != None:
            self.printInorder(node.left)
            print node.data
            self.printInorder(node.right)

    def findNode(self,node,value):
        if self.root != None:
            if value == node.data:
                return node.data
            elif value < node.data and node.left != None:
                self.findNode(node.left,value)
            elif value > node.data and node.right != None:
                self.findNode(node.right,value)
        else:
            return None
testTree = Tree()
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 200)
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 300)
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 100)
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 30)
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 20)
#testTree.printInorder(testTree.root)
print testTree.findNode(testTree.root,20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function without an explicit return will return None.

You have not returned the recursive calls within `findNode`. So, here.

```
if value == node.data:
    return node.data
elif value < node.data and node.left != None:
    return self.findNode(node.left,value)
elif value > node.data and node.right != None:
    return self.findNode(node.right,value)
```

---

Now, I can't help but thinking this is a bit noisy. You'll always start adding from the root, yes?

```
testTree.addNode(testTree.root, 200)
```

You could rather do this

```
testTree.addNode(200)
```

And to do that, you basically implement your methods on the `TreeNode` class instead. So, for the `addNode`.

You could also "return up" from the recursion, rather than "pass down" the nodes as parameters.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = value

    def addNode(self,value):
        if self.data == None:  # Ideally, should never end-up here
            self.data = value
        else:
            if value < self.data:
                if self.left == None:
                    self.left = TreeNode(value)
                else:
                    self.left = self.left.addNode(value)
            else:
                if self.right == None:
                    self.right = TreeNode(value)
                else:
                    self.right = self.right.addNode(value)

        return self # Return back up the recursion
```

Then, in the `Tree` class, just delegate the `addNode` responsibility to the root

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addNode(self,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)
        else:
            self.root = self.root.addNode(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you recurse to children in `findNode` you need to return the result, otherwise the function will implicitly return `None`:

```
def findNode(self,node,value):
    if self.root != None:
        if value == node.data:
            return node.data
        elif value < node.data and node.left != None:
            return self.findNode(node.left,value) # Added return
        elif value > node.data and node.right != None:
            return self.findNode(node.right,value) # Added return
    else:
        return None
```